# saving NSMutuableArray to NSUserDefault gives warning

Tags: objective-c

I have `NSMutuableArray` of UIImages . when trying to save him to `userDefaults`, i get warning.
If its an array of strings, its working ok.

```
//save to memory
    NSMutableArray *savedImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int j=0;j<[selectedButtonsTags count];j++)
        [savedImages addObject:[assets objectAtIndex:[[selectedButtonsTags objectAtIndex:j] intValue]]];
    [memoryInstance setTempImagesToSend:savedImages]; //here save to NSUserDefault
    [savedImages release];
```

warning :

```
[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value
```

Why the userdefault care what objects my array holds ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs for `NSUserDefaults`:

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData. For more details, see Preferences and Settings Programming Guide.

You will notice that `UIImage` is not in the list. You must convert the `UIImage` to an `NSData` object first before you can store the image in `NSUserDefaults`.

However, you should not use `NSUserDefaults` to store lots of binary data. Instead, write the images to the filesystem. Store them in an appropriate folder within the app's sandbox. You can store the filenames in `NSUserDefaults` if needed.